# Google Bigquery How to convert lag() funcion result to timestamp

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi is it possible to convert the result of a lag function to timestamp. I basically want to get the diff of two timestamp in seconds.
With the following codes the system tells me that the type of 'last_timestamp' is unknown. When i put the mouse cursor on the column 'last_timestamp' of the inner query, then i can see that its of type timestamp.

```
SELECT clientId, timestamp
  FROM (
        SELECT clientId, timestamp,
               LAG(timestamp,1) OVER
                 (PARTITION BY clientId ORDER BY timestamp)
                 AS last_timestamp
          FROM [oxidation.201602]
       ) last
 WHERE (TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(timestamp) - TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(last_timestamp) >= (60 * 30))
    OR last_timestamp IS NULL
```

Comment: I think you want something like SELECT clientId, timestamp, last_timestamp, timestamp-last_time stamp FROM...

Comment: HI Thanx for the hint. But how can i convert the result of the diff in total of seconds or munites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT clientId, timestamp
FROM (
  SELECT clientId, timestamp, timestamp_sec,
    LAG(timestamp_sec, 1) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY clientId ORDER BY timestamp_sec) AS prev_timestamp_sec
  FROM (
    SELECT clientId, timestamp, TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(timestamp) as timestamp_sec 
    FROM [oxidation.201602]
  )
) last
WHERE timestamp_sec - prev_timestamp_sec >= 60 * 30
OR prev_timestamp_sec IS NULL
```